# Using 'true' as a type in typescript

Tags: typescript

Today I found a strange behavior in Typescript.

I had a class defined as:

```
class MyClass {
  myMember: true;
}
```

That compiled and tslinted without any errors. The member wasn't used at all in typescript code, but I was referring to it in Angular.

As you can imagine what I wanted to do was:

```
class MyClass {
  myMember = true;
}
```

So obviously Angular wasn't seeing the value set to that property.

But my question is why that compiled? Is 'true' being understand as a type? Am I missing something in my tsconfig.json that will make that line throw an error?

Just wondering if there is anything I can define to capture similar errors and also trying to understand the logic behind making that a compilable piece of code.

Comment: Thanks @MuratK. didn't found that question but it is exactly the same as mine.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I missing something in my tsconfig.json that will make that line throw an error?

Yes, you are. You can set additional compiler options to get this effect.

In your case, set the compiler options `--strictPropertyInitialization` and `--strictNullChecks` to `true` in your tsconfig.

This will raise the error:

> Property 'myMember' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Consider adding other [compiler options](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) as well.

You can enable all `strict` type checking options by enabling the compiler option of the same name, `--strict`, to true.

You can also test the aforementioned two compiler options with your code on the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html). It has an "Options" menu to test *some* of the available compiler options in TypeScript.

Comment: Don't think that is exactly the answer. If I keep defining it as type 'true' but assign it to true in the constructor it will compile.

Comment: @Juan My answer only addresses the first example you gave that you wanted to have a compiler error for. The second case is absolutely valid. If you are interested in _why_ it is valid you can read the answers to the question marked as duplicate.